# can't make sense of valgrind output

Tags: valgrind, memcheck

Can't make sense of .eh_frame section mapping

```
     ==4780== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
     ==4780==    at 0x4011D18: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==    by 0x401628F: ???
     ==4780==    by 0x4006227: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==    by 0x40065EF: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==    by 0x4009E33: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==    by 0x400B437: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==    by 0x400A29F: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==    by 0x4002ECB: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==    by 0x400DF03: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==    by 0x4001BD3: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==    by 0x400215F: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==    by 0x400EF2B: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
    ==4780==
     ==4780== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
     ==4780==    at 0x4011D28: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
     ==4780==
     --4780-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
```

Comment: helllo, is anyone there?

Answer (score 1):

The output you show is indicative of `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` having been stripped.

Normally default Valgrind suppressions would have suppressed this output (since you can't do anything about these errors anyway). Installing glibc-debug-2.3.2* package might help.

Recent Valgrind versions refuse to run when `ld-linux.so.2` is stripped. However, since you are using *ancient* `glibc-2.3.2` (released in Mar 2003), you are probably also using ancient version of Valgrind, which  doesn't.

Comment: Valgrind 3.7.0 is the version, Iam using.

Comment: Hmm, 5 years later that's still the Valgrind version in Raspbian debs.  And I also see "Use of uninitialised value of size 4".  I'm not sure I've ever seen Valgrind work but I keep hoping.